# Continuous touch event on button in cocos2d

Tags: iphone

How do i get Continuous touch event on button in cocos2d.
Is there any method or properties for that?
I don't want to touch multiple time just touch the button work smooth.

Thank You.

Comment: Why do you need more than one touch event if nothing about the touch changes?

Answer (score 2):

1. On touch-begin event (set a boolean variable called touched to true).
2. On touch-move event (if touched is true, then do whatever u want for the continuous processing you want to do).
3. On touch-event event (set touched variable to false, and stop whatever continues processing you were doing).

Comment: so this only works if the touch is moving?  That's not what he's looking for